# Restful API expects byte[] / ByteArrayInputStream - how to encode on the client?

Tags: .net, json, rest

In a RESTful service there is a method which in the request expects:

```
@XmlElement(required = true)
public byte[] data;
```

From that the implementation creates a:

```
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(request.data);
```

If I want to use this API from a (.NET) client, what do I have to put into the request?
I tried already to pass a Base64 encoded string, but that results in an error.
Am I really supposed to convert this to a string representation?

```
{
...
"data" : {"01", "31", "AC", ...}
...
}
```

The overhead would be catastrophic!